# Using multipart/form-data in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I have a requirement of uploading a pdf file to the a third-party API to do that what we are using a controller and then sending its buffer to the endpoint in multipart/form-data but It's not working. What am i doing wrong??

I have my controller defined like

```js
    @Post('/upload')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    async uploadDocument(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File){
        await this.httpRequestService.uploadDocument(file)
        return [
            Translation.translate('Create_Success_Message', {
                Entity: 'File'
            }),
            {
                file
            }
        ]
    }
```

This controller calls a service called `uploadDocument` which looks like:

```js
async uploadDocument(file){
        try{
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', file)
        const response = await this.httpService.post(`urlWhereItHits`,
        formData, 
        {   
            headers:{ 
                "X-AppSecretToken":"appsecrettoken",
                "X-AgreementGrantToken":"agreementgranttoken",
                'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            
        }).toPromise();
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
}
```

Now i don't understand what's happening wrong here.
I get error saying
`TypeError: source.on is not a function at Function.DelayedStream.create (C:\Users\Tushar\Squire-backend\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar task, receiving a .csv file and sending it to another server.

controller:

```js
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    @Post('upload')
    async uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
      
      await this.myService.uploadFile(file);
      return {
        message: 'File uploaded successfully.',
      };
    }
```

service:

```js
    import * as FormData from 'form-data';
    import { Readable } from 'stream';
    
    async uploadFile(file: Express.Multer.File) {
    const form = new FormData();

    form.append('files', Readable.from(file.buffer), {
      filename: file.originalname,
    });

    try {
      const result = await lastValueFrom(
        this.httpService.post('The URL of your third-party service', form, {
          headers: {
            ...form.getHeaders(),
          },
        }),
      );

      if (result.status === 200) return;
    } catch {
      
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(
        'Error while uploading the .csv file.',
      );
    }
    }
```

Some explanations here:

- It requires importing `Formdata` from the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data).
- `.append()` requires a fieldName, and a readable Stream.
- You can use the buffer of the file that's on memory (not recommended with large files) and use it to create a readable stream.
- Also, you need to add the name of the file manually since `Formdata` only recognizes the filename if the file is saved on disk. (Which in our case is on memory as a Buffer).
- You can create the stream in different ways, the example is not mandatory.
- `.getHeaders()` will generate the default header `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` and also it will generate the boundary of the file, like this: [reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data#axios)

```
      {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------286308325485491440714225'
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also this short then previous suggestions, and result are same

import * as FormData from 'form-data';

async uploadFile(file: Express.Multer.File) {
const form = new FormData();

```
form.append('files', file.buffer, { filename: file.originalname });

try {
    const result = await lastValueFrom(
        this.httpService.post('thrid party API url', form, headers),
    );
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

}